# Accessing app-argument from Smart App Banner

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm just learning how to use Smart App Banners to display a banner for my iOS app on a web page.  Is it possible to access the `app-argument` value specified in the banner if your app is built with React Native?

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue and I thought the app-argument would trigger my deep-lining listener but it doesn't.

Answer (score -3):

Your app is on the App Store, right? If so, yes, it is absolutely possible.

Go here: https://tools.applemediaservices.com/app-store

And do this:

> Type the name of your app in the Search field, and select the
> appropriate country or region and media type. In the results, select
> your app. In the detail view for your app, find the Content Link. Your
> app ID is the number between id and ?. Alternatively, select your app
> in App Store Connect. Under General, select App Information, then find
> your app ID in the General Information section that opens in the
> middle of the screen; your app ID is listed as Apple ID.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners

Comment: I'm not asking how to get the app ID. I'm asking how to get access to any other arguments which are used to launch it.

Comment: Afraid not - I gave up!